# Why didn't the dragons burn him?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In Season 6, Episode 2...

> Tyrion goes down to the dungeon, meeting the dragons for the first time. The dragons were about to burn him, but stop. They even allow him to come close enough to touch them. Tyrion previously said dragons are smart and understand things, which is why the second dragon allowed him to live.

If the dragons are frustrated living in a dungeon for so long, and they see a stranger, why didn't they attack? If somebody familiar went down to free them, it would be understandable, but why wouldn't they attack a complete stranger?

Comment: Voting to close as "future works".

Comment: You may also be interested in this fan theory about Tyrion's parentage: [What is A+J=T?](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php?/topic/134727-ajt-v7/)

Comment: Dragons have keen senses.  Tyrion drinks, and knows things.  They smell that he's saturated with alcohol, inside and out.  If they burn him, there is a great danger of an alcohol-based flash-fire/explosion that could backfire on them.

Comment: Here I was about to make a circus midget joke, but @PoloHoleSet's joke was much better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is this from [the books' wiki](http://m.westeros.org/index.php/Quentyn_Martell):

> Quentyn's companions are keen to return to Dorne but Quentyn refuses
>  to go. He does not want to return having failed.
>  
>  
>  He hatches a plan, hoping that he will be able to tame at least one of
>  the dragons due to his Targaryen ancestry. For this purpose, he
>  arranges a meeting with the Tattered Prince, hiring the Windblown's
>  help in seizing Rhaegal and Viserion. The Tattered Prince agrees,
>  asking for Pentos in return. Quentyn signs an agreement.
>  
>  
>  Dressed as Brazen Beasts, Quentyn and his companions go to the pit
>  where the dragons are kept. The Tattered Prince had given them the
>  code word to be used by the Brazen Beasts that day (dog), but with
>  Barristan Selmy's coup occurring at the same time, the Brazen Beasts
>  guarding the door are not aware of the code word.
>  
>  Gaining access to the dragons, Quentyn eventually attempts to tame
>  Viserion, but Rhaegal attacks Quentyn from behind, and bathes him in
>  dragonfire. The Windblown mercenaries flee, and both dragons escape.
>  
>  Missandei takes care of Quentyn, but he dies in Daenerys Targaryen's
>  bed four days later, covered in burns. Upon seeing the extent of the
>  prince's injuries, Ser Barristan thinks it would have been better if
>  Rhaegal had just eaten him alive, as his death would haven been
>  quicker and less painful in such a case.

It contradicts, but could imply that Tyrion just has very valiant despite his small stature.  Quentyn thought his blood was enough, whereas Tyrion has the confidence to tame them.

It really makes no sense and is inconsistent with the book, so who really knows?  Bad storytelling maybe.

TLDR; A possible theory is that the dragons recognized Tyrion's confidence and respected that.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question though... Quentyn in the books has nothing to do with Tyrion in the show so I'm not sure how 90% of the answer is relevant.

Comment: Its speculation because there isn't a definitive answer as the show has deviated so far from the book and the show doesn't provide an answer.  Its an answer because it would help explain why the show does this.  In any case it makes no sense.

Comment: fair enough. Maybe a tldr section for the answer so that a show watcher can avoid the whole Quentyn story?

Answer (score 9):

This is all speculation on my part, but since there is nothing to prove anything 100% I guess I can speculate a bit.

> Tyrion said dragons are very intelligent. This could very well mean that they can judge character very well. He seemed to have their best interests at heart so they did not hurt him.

They might have tested him as well.

> He also did not try to run away when the dragons tried to intimidate him. This might have been enough proof for them that he wouldn't try to hurt them.

Why would he even attempt anything like this?

> I have read that Tyrion has a real good knowledge on dragons, probably more so than Dany has because Tyrion has always been fascinated by them.